# Is exposing SignalR connectionid a security risk

Tags: security, signalr

I'm working on a chat app that's using signalr. I'm associating each user by their connectionid.

I'm just wondering if I broadcast all the users connectionids so anyone can see them in the code, would someone be able to cause any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing the connection ID is not a security risk as far as I know, sharing the *connection token* however is one.

From my own testing with SignalR it doesn't check the origin of a message but only the connection token, which is a encrypted form of the connection ID plus the username (if I remember correctly) if the session is authenticated (which is also why you need to reconnect after authenticating).

I was successfully able to spoof a SignalR connection from another computer on another IP with version 2.0.2 just by replacing the connection token.

Comment: Are you sure? According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization): _You should never pass one client's connection id to other clients, as a malicious user could use it to mimic a request from that client._

Answer (score 0):

The old accepted answer here is wrong according to [the most recent documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which states:

> Exposing ConnectionId can lead to malicious impersonation if the SignalR server or client version is ASP.NET Core 2.2 or earlier. If the SignalR server and client version are ASP.NET Core 3.0 or later, the ConnectionToken rather than the ConnectionId must be kept secret. The ConnectionToken is purposely not exposed in any API. It can be difficult to ensure that older SignalR clients aren't connecting to the server, so even if your SignalR server version is ASP.NET Core 3.0 or later, the ConnectionId shouldn't be exposed.